# .htaccess Rewrite rule not working - wildcards

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simple url rewrite:

Url is e.g.

```
http://mydm.com/search/this/could/be/anything
```

The only critical word here is search - I want this to resolve to:

```
http://mydm.com/pages/search.html
```

This is what I'm trying but I get a `404` error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])$ /pages/search.html
```

Am I doing the wildcard matching wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/ /pages/search.html [NC,L]
```